# How can I get rid of this ClassCastException? (java)

Tags: java, arrays, exception, object, casting

I am trying to create an array of the generic class "DataStruct".
The code is the following:

```
public class DataArray<T> {
DataStruct<T>[] array;
int index;

public DataArray(int capacity) {
    array = (DataStruct<T>[]) new Object[capacity]; // !!!
    this.index = 0;
}
}
```

I get a  java.lang.ClassCastException (Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LArrayBased.DataStruct;) at the line marked with three exclamation marksat the end, while testing it.

Can you please tell me the correct way to create it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not declare

```
array = new DataStruct[capacity];
```

`Object[]` can not be cast to `DataStruct[]`.

Because arrays are refiable in nature that means arrays know their type at runtime so If you convert it to `Object []` like below you will again run in to problems

```
Object[] array = new DataStruct[capacity]; 
array[0] = 10;//Array Store exception
```

So it is wise to declare it as `DataStruct[capacity]`

Comment: The other way around is also impossible (DataStruct[] cannot be converted to Object[])

Comment: @amit Arrays are covarant in nature so `Object being super type of DataStruct so  other way around is allowed`.